# How to get clear image after low frequency suppression of image?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I'm suppressing the low DC frequencies of several (unequal) blocks in an image in the Dicrete Cosine Transform (DCT) domain. After that doing an inverse DCT to get back the image with only the high frequency portions remaining.

```
  cvConvertScale( img , img_32 ); //8bit to 32bit conversion 
cvMinMaxLoc( img_32, &Min, &Max ); 
cvScale( img_32 , img_32 , 1.0/Max ); //quantization for 32bit 

cvDCT( img_32 , img_dct , CV_DXT_FORWARD ); //DCT 
//display( img_dct, "DCT");

cvSet2D(img_dct, 0,  0, cvScalar(0)); //suppress constant background

//cvConvertScale( img_dct, img_dct, -1, 255 ); //invert colors

cvDCT( img_dct , img_out , CV_DXT_INVERSE ); //IDCT
//display(img_out, "IDCT");
```

[image] 
[image]
[image]

The objective is to identify and isolate elements which is present in high frequencies from previously detected regions in the image. However in several  cases the text is very thin and faint (low contrast). In these cases the IDCT yeilds images which are so dark that even the high frequency portions become too faint for further analysis to work.

What manipulations are there so that we can obtain a clearer picture from the IDCT after background suppression? `CvEqualizeHist()` gives too much noise.

**EDIT:**

[Whole picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9ZEy.jpg) uploaded here as belisarius asked. The low frequency suppression is not being done on the entire image, but on small ROI set to the smallest bounding rectangle around text/low frequency portions.

Comment: Setting the DCT coefficient `(0, 0)` to zero will not remove any noise. It will just subtract the entire image's gray level with a constant (which is the mean gray level of the original image). The new image will contain as much high-frequency noise as the original.

Comment: In the three test samples in your screenshot, I think a simple threshold should be able to separate the text from the background. You may want to take a look at binary-thresholding algorithms.

Comment: @Nick ODell: no they aren't captchas. just indian text detected from really messed-up low-quality street scenes.

Comment: @rwong - the main aim is not to eliminate noise initially, but trying to eliminate the constant background first. I tried Otsu's thresholding, as well as local adaptive, however its not really working out. could you give any specific references you think might work? Also it'd be great if you could give code/algo that's help with the high-freq noise while suppressing constant background (latter i already did).

Comment: What is the goal you have with isolating high frequencies? Perhaps there is some other way to achieve that.

Comment: If you post bigger images, perhaps we can try a few tricks ...

Comment: thats the thing, the images are very small regions. Resizing distorts the text. still will be uploading asap.

Comment: @belisarius: uploaded link to larger image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your example image, Let's start with one possible strategy to isolate the text.

The code is in Mathematica.

```
(* Import your image*)
i1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYwx8.jpg"];
i = ImageData@i1;
```

[image]

```
(*Get the red channel*)
j = i[[All, All, 1]]
(*Perform the DCT*)
t = FourierDCT[j];
(*Define a high pass filter*)
truncate[data_, f_] :=
  Module[{i, j},
   {i, j} = Floor[Dimensions[data]/Sqrt[f]];
   PadRight[Take[data, -i, -j], Dimensions[data], 0.]
   ];

(*Apply the HP filter, and do the reverse DCT*)
k = Image[FourierDCT[truncate[t, 4], 3]] // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

```
(*Appy a Gradient Filter and a Dilation*)
l = Dilation[GradientFilter[k, 1] // ImageAdjust, 5]
```

[image]

```
(*Apply a MinFilter and Binarize*)
m = Binarize[MinFilter[l, 10], .045]
```

[image]

```
(*Perform a Dilation and delete small components to get a mask*)
mask = DeleteSmallComponents@Dilation[m, 10]
```

[image]

```
(*Finally apply the mask*)
ImageMultiply[mask, Image@i]
```

[image]

*To be continued ...*

**Edit**

Answering questions in comments:

The `GradientFilter` description is under "more information" here: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GradientFilter.html.

The `MinFilter` description is under "more information" here: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MinFilter.html

Comment: looks like this is it. just a few more questions: is the Gradient Filter the same as the Morphology Gradient function in OpenCV? Secondly, what is a MinFilter (sorry these things may have slightly diff OpenCV equivalents for me).

Comment: @AruniRC Sorry, no OpenCV here, but I updated the post with the description of the operators used.

Comment: thanks, stuff's clear now. the objective wasn't to isolate the high frequency portions from the whole image, but somehow "clean-up" the regions i got after a few simple filters like Stroke Width etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can improve the contrast by applying a simple positive power law transformation prior to applying the discrete cosine transform, or after the IDCT. That will move the shades of gray farther apart. Try this:

```
cvPow(img, img_hicontrast, 1.75); // Adjust the exponent to your needs
cvConvertScale(img_highcontrast, img_32);
```

Comment: this seems promising. some more finetuning to do with results, but it could work.

Comment: Tinker with the exponent. Or try placing cvPow after the inverse DCT.

Comment: placing it after inverse DCT doesn't make much difference. I suppose the values are so low that even the power doesn't separate them much.

Answer (score 3):

If a simple threshold (+ maybe some morphological opening) is not enough, I would suggest to try using a diffusion filter: it smooths the noise in areas without edges, but preserves the edges very well. After that, the segmentation should become easier.

If the edges are becoming too faint after your frequency domain filtering, overpainting them with the result of a `cvCanny()` before filtering can help a lot, especially if you manage to find the right smoothing level, to get only the useful edges.